# The Hulk and the Thing fall from space - Marvel comic

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification

I have a memory niggling from many years ago (late 1960s to early 1970s) about a story in Marvel.

There were like slaver space pirates who used solar sails and three mast galleons to fly through space, they also used slave oarsmen somehow.

When they needed new slaves they went to the nearest inhabited planet and grabbed the strongest specimens.

Anyways they now have Hulk and Thing (personal air shields comes to mind) but trouble starts between the mighty pair and they end up falling from space back to Earth.

Some guy with his cute little daughter points up at the night sky "Look honey, a shooting star"

The daughter must have had superpower vision "No daddy, it looks like two men, they've fell from the sky and can't ever get back up there"

A long shot but is there a FOOM who can help identify the story?

Comment: What does FOOM mean?

Comment: @Clockwork 51 - many years ago you could get badges and passes to show you were a "Friend Of Ol' Marvel"

Comment: @Clockwork, a '70s [house ad for FOOM.](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Ex-x_NbDcUk/UQn9tDYIWlI/AAAAAAAAEm8/wFiwLu-tCng/s1600/15Marvel+merchandise21.jpg)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is [*Incredible Hulk Vol. 1* Issue 137](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Incredible_Hulk_Vol_1_137). It is the [Andromeda starship](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Andromeda_(Starship)) they are on which does look quite like a pirate ship but I don't believe it is. It also isn't the Thing with Hulk but rather Abomination who was the First Mate aboard the Andromeda.

The panels you are thinking of happen right at the end of the story/issue. Hulk and Abomination fight each other as they fall from the Andromeda into Earth. A little girl and a dad stare up at the "shooting stars" and the girl makes the comment you remember.

[image: Hulk and Abomination are fighting in space. Abomination is out of strength, so he can't strike back, to which Hulk replies "Then-- Hulk-- Wins!" and strike Abomination down back to Earth, as he himself is out of strength and pulled down to Earth by the effect of gravity, while a spaceship called Andromeda is drifting away aimlessly because it is "captain-less". Meanwhile, a father is talking with his daughter, telling her that to make a wish, she should be wishing to the first star of the night (it's too late), or a shooting star. Suddenly, he notices what he believes to be a shooting star, to which his daughter replies: "But-- that looks more like two men, daddy-- two men who fell off a star-- -- and fell so far-- they can't ever get back again-- !"]

Comment: Thank you, I had to Google 'Abomination' - so many years since I read that story - fifty years!!!